# Laravel deployment to apache with php-fpm restart

Tags: laravel, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I'm quite new to laravel and the concept of CI/CD. But I have invested the last 24 hours to get something up and running. Actually I'm using [gitlab.com](http://https//gitlab.com) as repo. There I have configured the CI/CD functionality.

The deployments should be done to `SRV1` which has configured its corresponding user with a cert. The `SRV1` should then clone the necessary files from the gitlab repo by using deployer. The gitlab repo also has the public key from `SRV1` user. This chain is working quite good.

The problem is, that after deploying I need to restart php-fpm so that it can reinitialize its symlinks and updates its absolute path cache.

I saw various methodes to overcome this with setting some cgi settings in php-fpm. But these didn't work for me since they all are using nginx, while I'm using apache.

Is there any other way to tell php-fpm with apache to reinitialize its paths or reload after changes?
The method to add the deployer user to the sudoers list and to call service restart php-fpm looks quite hacky to me...

Thanks

UPDATE1:

Actually I found this : https://github.com/lorisleiva/laravel-deployer/blob/master/docs/how-to-reload-fpm.md

It looks like, that deployer has some technique to do this. But this requires the deployer user to have acces to php-fpm reload. Looks a bit unsafe to me.

I didn't found any other solutions. there are some for nginx to tell nginx to always re-evaluate the real path. Obviously for Apache it should be "followSymLink" but it was not working.

Actually I created a bash script which is running under root. this script always check for changes in the "current" symlink every 10 seconds. if there was a change -> reload php-fpm. Not nice, of course quite ugly, but should work.

Still open for other proposals.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue on my server by adding a php file that clear APCU & OPCACHE :

```
<?php
if (in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', '::1']))
{
    apcu_clear_cache();
    apcu_clear_cache('user');
    apcu_clear_cache('opcode');
    opcache_reset();
    echo "Cache cleared";
}
else
{
    die("You can't clear cache");
}
```

then you have to call it with curl after you updated your symlink :

```
/usr/bin/curl --silent https://domain.ext/clear_apc_cache.php
```

I use Gitlab CI/CD it works now for me